# MySQL create a line with every new user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem

I want to create a script, that creates a new line in the table, if there is a new user and in the line, change the "points" column to zero (0).

This is my current code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1250');    
$firstName = $_POST['firstname'];

$servername = "db.mysql-01.gsp-europe.net";
$username = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to create table

$sql = "UPDATE `member_profile` SET points = points + 1 WHERE user_id = '$firstName'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Thingz created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error doing sum thingz: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

What I need in the cube: when there new user_id ($firstName) appears, create new line with this user name, and change the "points" column from "null" into Zero (0).

Thanks for your time, I appreciate it

Comment: I don't understand your problem : you want to create a NEW user with points = NULL then update this user with new points ? Maybe try to use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`, this way you can create a new user with the point you want and if user exists you update what you want

Comment: "_What i need in the cube_" What cube? "_creates a new line in the table_" You mean a new row?! Have you done anything yet, for now you just update existing data in your db, not inserting anything

Comment: Mind the SQL injections..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well you want to check if the user exists or not. If user is new create new line with the user with 0 points and if exist increse points with 1.

```php
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1250');  
if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){  
$firstName = $_POST['firstname'];



$servername = "db.mysql-01.gsp-europe.net";
$username = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// check if the user exist
$check = "SELECT * FROM `member_profile` WHERE user_id = '$firstName'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$check) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        //if exist increse points with 1
        if($rows>=1){

$sql = "UPDATE `member_profile` SET points = points + 1 WHERE user_id = '$firstName'";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Thingz created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error doing sum thingz: " . $conn->error;
}
        }
        //if don't exist create user with points 0
        if($rows==0)
        {
            $query = "INSERT into `member_profile` (user_id, points) VALUES ( '$firstName' ,'0')";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$conn->close();

        }
}

?>
```

Remember, I gave you an idea, the code is prone to sql inject

Comment: SQL injections and race conditions are possible here in short this code example is not very good..

Comment: I gave you an idea, you do not have to use the code.query is ok

Comment: *"I gave you an idea, you do not have to use the code.query is ok"* iám not the topicstarter, iam warning the topicstarter and future readers for hackable code which isn't good offcource..

Comment: I get an error, when I enter new name        Notice: Undefined variable: con in D:\xampp\htdocs\db.php on line 49

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\xampp\htdocs\db.php on line 49

Comment: @HnusnyPleb , replace or die(mysqli_error($con)); with or die(mysqli_error($conn));

Comment: @RaymondNijland , I'm sorry, I did not see, I'm new on the platform and I'm not used to it yet.

Comment: Okey, now it is showing : Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 error

Comment: @HnusnyPleb yes, you need to give a value to $firstName, this value come from your form, i edit my answer, try now

Comment: No. The problem was in "r_cr_time, r_created_by, r_site".. I must delete it.. Now its working.. Thankz

Comment: @HnusnyPleb , oh yea, I'm working on a project and I've got this in the clipboard. I have not seen. I apologize. I corrected.